# Switching from Ubuntu to Debian

Tags: debian, system-installation, 64bit

I want to switch from Ubuntu 16.04 to Debian 8.7.1.

I have the correct Debian ISO image on a USB stick. However, my computer will not boot from it, nor will it boot from a CD/DVD with the image on it either. It just flat out ignores the other boot media.

Oddly enough, my computer *will* boot from a USB stick if there is an Ubuntu ISO image on it.

I am using a PC with amd64 architecture. I've looked into [installing Debian from a Unix/Linux system](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/apds03.html.en) but that looks really messy.

Any advice?

Comment: Two possible problems: 1). Have you actually boot from a thumb drive (set in bios)? 2). Are you sure the thumb was flashed successfully? How you flashed an .iso to a thumb drive?

Comment: If I'm understanding your questions correctly: 1) yes, I'm entering boot options with f12 at startup. 2) I downloaded the iso onto my computer from debian, and then saved it onto my thumbdrive. That's how I 'flashed' the .iso to my thumbdrive.

Comment: 2). So have you just copied/moved an .iso file to your thumb drive? If so there is no way it would work. You have to actually *flash* it with `dd if=/path/to/your/iso of=/path/to/thumb/device bs=4M` (thumb device without partition number, i.e. `/dev/sdb`). You can also use a graphical tool like `unetbootin` but it has occasional problems with some distributions and modifies a boot sector so I would still recommend `dd`.

Comment: Next step, try booting from that usb drive on a different computer, with no Ubuntu installed.  I don't see how/why it should only boot a specific distro's media.

Comment: Good point I'll look into that. By the way I did not have to use dd with my Ubuntu install. Boy this is one confusing installation process.

Comment: I'd be curious to know the difference in process between you putting an Ubuntu ISO on your stick vs putting the Debian ISO on your stick. I would have expected the same process to work for both, since both Ubuntu and Debian generate hybrid bootable ISOs.

Comment: Hi. When I first installed Ubuntu over a year ago, I must have used something like Unetbootin to create my bootable USB stick. I honestly can't remember. My Ubuntu USB stick still works like a charm. In fact, I had to use it today to get my computer working after failing with Debian. When I finally got the USB stick working for Debian, I did the install and had firmware issues, Grub issues, incorrect password issues, even though my password was correct, BLAH BLAH BLAH. What a horrible experience. Maybe in the future I will take another crack at it but for now I'm sticking with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu ISO image is more compatible with machine. It support img/iso mirror boot-up at same time. Try dd with your debian iso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three attempts I managed to install Debian 8.7.1 on my computer and I am very happy with it.

The issues with my installation attempts were 1) bad ISO, 2) firmware issues, which relates to 3) unable to configure apt during installation. I corrected my ISO problems, found an ISO with firmware, and ran the Debian installer via ethernet. It worked like a charm.

Here are the steps:

Download ISO from Debian (this iso includes firmware and gnome):

```
https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/8.7.1-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-8.7.1-amd64-gnome-desktop+nonfree.iso
```

insert your USB and locate it with:

```
lsblk
```

wipe the USB disk clean (change sdx to your device):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx
```

now create the ISO:

```
cd ~/Downloads

sudo dd if=debian-live-8.7.1-amd64-gnome-desktop+nonfree.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1M
```

Next turn off your wifi and be sure you are connected to ethernet. Restart your computer and enter boot options (for me that means holding down f12). Choose graphic install. And that's it. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a program like unetbootin or Linux Live USB Creator to extract the image to the flash drive, or, if you use cd/dvd a burning software. Don't just copy the iso in them. It will not work like that. And don't mess with complicated techniques like the ones in the link you provided. It can also be done that way, but why bother if you can use tools that do it right?

Comment: "Please note, that Debian advises not using unetbootin for this task. It can cause difficult-to-diagnose problems with booting and installing, so is not recommended." - https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/

Comment: Despite the fact it works like a charm! I have never experienced a problem all these years.